# Script not changing json value

Tags: python, json

I have a python script that monitors how many times a code has been used but when I call this function.

```
def addUse(key):
    with open ("keys.json") as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
        role = False
        for d in data["keys"]:
            if(d["key"] == key):
                d["uses"] = d["uses"] + 1
                role = d
        return role
        f.close()

    with open ("keys.json", "w+") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data))
        f.close()
```

It doesn't change the value `uses`.

Comment: The function has a `return` statement inside the first block that reads the json file.  It never reaches the second block to write the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first block of code to read the json file contains a `return` statement, which causes the function to immediately terminate.  It never reaches the second block to re-write the json file.

Also, a few side comments:

You don't need to explicitly `close()` a file that was opened in a `with` block; it is closed automatically when the block ends.  (And in fact that's the entire point of the `with` statement -- the resource is automatically closed when the block exits, *no matter how* the block is exited.)

If you have an open file object, you can use `json.dump(data, f)`.  You don't need to convert to a string with `dumps()` and then call `write()`.